# Добавить поддержку touch к слайдеру

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли (если да, то как) добавить поддержку touch к **[этому слайдеру](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/)**?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что конкретно на touch там довесить?

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы данный слайдер, на мобильных устройствах (iPad) пролистывался с помощью жестов.

Comment: @Astor, может [статья на русском](http://habrahabr.ru/post/158577/) вам поможет?

Comment: Всем спасибо! Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Spawn, преобразуйте Ваш комментарий в ответ. Спасибо. Очень помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взять, например, нечто такое и не трудно будет прикрутить

[jQuery Touchwipe Plugin](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library)

Comment: @Spawn, а Вы случайно не в курсе, как сделать так, чтобы при жесте вверх/вниз на слайдере, страница прокручивалась? 

Сам слайдер листается отлично влево и вправо, а вот если попытаться прокрутить страницу, то ...

Answer (score 2):

Конечно можно отслеживать перемещения вручную, и выставлять координаты слайдеру, но проще воспользоваться готовками.

В своё время юзал эту штуку: [`swiper`](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php). Его легко использовать, но при этом богатое `api`